# AWS SQS Queue not receiving messages from SNS Topic subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

In my cloudformation template I have the following for my SQS queue:

```
OutputQueuePolicy:
  Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal: "*"
          Action:
            - "sqs:SendMessage"
          Resource:
            Fn::GetAtt: [OutputQueue, Arn]
          Condition:
            ArnEquals:
              aws:SourceArn: !Ref OutputTopic
            Bool:
              aws:SecureTransport: "false"
    Queues:
      - Ref: OutputQueue

OutputQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: isolation-change-output-queue
    RedriveAllowPolicy:
      redrivePermission: byQueue
      sourceQueueArns:
        - Fn::GetAtt: [OutputDeadLetterQueue, Arn]
    RedrivePolicy:
      deadLetterTargetArn:
        Fn::GetAtt: [OutputDeadLetterQueue, Arn]
      maxReceiveCount: 5

OutputDeadLetterQueuePolicy:
  Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Deny"
          Principal: "*"
          Action:
            - "sqs:SendMessage"
            - "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
          Resource: "*"
          Condition:
            Bool:
              aws:SecureTransport: "false"
    Queues:
      - Ref: OutputDeadLetterQueue

OutputDeadLetterQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: isolation-change-output-dead-letter-queue
```

And here is my SNS topic:

```
OutputTopicPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: "Allow-SQS-to-receive-messages-from-topic"
          Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Service: "sqs.amazonaws.com"
          Action: "sns:Publish"
          Resource:
            Ref: OutputTopic
          Condition:
            ArnEquals:
              "aws:SourceArn":
                Fn::GetAtt:
                  - OutputQueue
                  - Arn
    Topics:
      - Ref: OutputTopic

OutputTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    TopicName: isolation-change-output-topic

OutputQueueSNSSubscription:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
    Endpoint:
      Fn::GetAtt: [OutputQueue, Arn]
    Protocol: "sqs"
    RedrivePolicy:
      deadLetterTargetArn:
        Fn::GetAtt: [OutputDeadLetterQueue, Arn]
    TopicArn: !Ref OutputTopic
```

I'm attempting to publish messages to the topic via the AWS SDK, but the messages don't seem to making it to the queue. I'm not receiving any errors, and I'm not sure what's wrong with my cloudformation template.

Answer (score 1):

Your Amazon SQS queue **requires an Access Policy** that permits the Amazon SNS Topic to send a message to the Amazon SQS queue.

I deployed your stack and added this policy to the SQS queue:

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:isolation-change-output-dead-letter-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:isolation-change-output-topic"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I was then able to **successfully** send a message to the SNS topic and it appeared in the SQS queue.

The policy was copied from: [Subscribing an Amazon SQS queue to an Amazon SNS topic - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscribe-sqs-queue-to-sns-topic.html)

You would need to add a similar to policy to your `OutputDeadLetterQueuePolicy`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does my OutputQueuePolicy not already contain this?

Comment: No. There is no policy on your **queue** that allows access from SNS. Instead, `OutputTopicPolicy` is an SNS policy that is attempting to grant the topic permission to send to SQS, but this will not work. Instead, it needs to be a **policy on the SQS queue** that grants access from SNS. See [Publish messages to an Amazon SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-publish-messages-to-sqs-queue) and read the warning in the blue box _"The example presented below is an Amazon SQS policy, not an Amazon SNS policy."_